# XML Cannot Read using Select

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

```
    <Attendance xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ZKWebApi">
  <Records>
    <Record>
      <EnrollNumber>1</EnrollNumber>
      <EntryTime>2015-02-16T00:13:00</EntryTime>
      <InOutMode>0</InOutMode>
      <VerifyMode>3</VerifyMode>
    </Record>
  </Records>
</Attendance>
```

I try to insert this Xml and Read the Properties from Select Statemant this is not reading values are not coming.

This is my select query

```
SELECT t.CARD_NO, t.INOUT_MODE,t.VERIFY_MODE
 FROM XMLTABLE ('/Attendance/Records/Record'
               PASSING (SELECT xmlcol FROM BIZZXE_V2_SCH.BB)
               COLUMNS CARD_NO               NUMBER PATH 'EnrollNumber',
                       INOUT_MODE            NUMBER PATH 'InOutMode',
                       VERIFY_MODE           NUMBER PATH 'VerifyMode') T;
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "values are not coming."  What happens?  Blank rows?  No rows?  Error message?

Comment: No  Errors Just Blanks

Comment: I think can't find the path

Comment: There is something wrong with your namespace declaration. Try <Attendance xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:j="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ZKWebApi">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t.CARD_NO, t.INOUT_MODE,t.VERIFY_MODE
 FROM XMLTABLE ( XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as "i", default 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ZKWebApi' ),'/Attendance/Records/Record'
               PASSING (SELECT xmlcol FROM BIZZXE_V2_SCH.BB)
               COLUMNS CARD_NO               NUMBER PATH 'EnrollNumber',
                       INOUT_MODE            NUMBER PATH 'InOutMode',
                       VERIFY_MODE           NUMBER PATH 'VerifyMode') T;
```

Defult namespace for your xml is set for xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ZKWebApi". And you have to add this information in xmltable.